# How to get individual outputs as individual files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python program which takes random numbers as input and give a number of separate outputs. The run file is from 
This answer[The norm of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282535/12540979). So how to modify the run file to get each new (x,y,z) output in seperate data files like 1.txt,2.txt....20.txt

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the same 'Test.py'

```
import math
class Vector():
    def __init__(self,vx,vy,vz):
        self.x=vx
        self.y=vy
        self.z=vz

    def norm(self):
        xx=self.x**2
        yy=self.y**2
        zz=self.z**2
        return math.sqrt(xx+yy+zz)
```

Add a counter to keep track of the valid output file to be created

```
import math
import numpy as np

from Desktop import Test

def random_range(n, min, max):
    return min + np.random.random(n) * (max - min)

file_count = 1
x = random_range(20,2,9)
y = random_range(20,2,9)
z = random_range(20,2,9)

trial_args = np.stack((x, y, z), axis=-1)
for x, y, z in trial_args:
    model=Test.Vector(x,y,z)

    if model.norm() > 5:
        ifp = open(str(file_count) + ".txt", "w")
        ifp.write("{}, {}, {} => {}".format(x, y, z, model.norm()))
        ifp.close()
        file_count += 1
```

Comment: If there is no if statement and I want to print all outputs as file than ifp causing problem

Comment: Missed a bracket in the ifp.write line. Try again.